# EntityFramework 6.1.3 with WCF. Memory Consumption w3wp.exe

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, wcf, npgsql, w3wp

```
 public IEnumerable<FormsDto> GetForms(int TId, int AId)
    {
        using (var context = new NewEntities())
        {
            try
            {
                context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
                var FormList = (from NAC in context.Candidates.AsNoTracking().Where(d => d.IsDeleted == false && d.StatusId == 1 && d.TId == TenantId && d.AId == AId)
                                           select new FormsDto
                                           {
                                               CandidateId = NAC.CandidateId,
                                               ApplicationUserId = NAC.ApplicationUserId ?? 0,
                                               ChildName = NAC.CandidateFirstName + " " + ((NAC.CandidateMiddleName == null) ? "" : NAC.CandidateMiddleName) + " " + NAC.CandidateLastName,
                                               TID = NAC.TId ?? 0,
                                               AID = NAC.AId ?? 0,
                                               Classid = NAC.ClassId ?? 0,
                                               FormNo = NAC.FormNo
                                           }).ToList();

                foreach (FormsDto item in FormList)
                {
                    int classid = context.Classes.AsNoTracking().Where(d => d.IsDeleted == false && d.ClassId == item.Classid).FirstOrDefault().ClassId ?? 0;
                    item.ClassName = context.Classes.AsNoTracking().Where(d => d.ClassID == classid && d.IsDeleted == false && d.TID == item.TID).FirstOrDefault().Displaylabel;

                }
                return FormList;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

> Above is my WCF method.When gets called(returns 8/9 records),w3wp.exe consumes high memory upto 150MB. I just want to know is my approach is right whatever i hav return above.

Comment: I deleted my previous comment because I thought there could be an issue by using AsNoTracking() before your Where() clause, but it returns IQueryable, so it is fine. Are you calling this method for the first time when you start your WCF service?  If you are, then this will 'start up' the service for the first time, the initialisation could consume a lot of memory.  Does it take just as long when calling for a second time?

Comment: 1)Yes calling this method for the first time when  WCF service starts.2)when calling for a second time / subsequent requests w3wp.exe  consumes more 5/6 MB.Since i am using --using (var context = new NewEntities())--why memory is not getting freed since context gets disposed after each request

Comment: So it is better after the second request?  I believe that using a `using` statement just tells the garbage collector that it __can__ be freed now, it doesn't instruct the garbage collector to free it right now.

Comment: so is it good force GC after each wcf service call in finally block-----GC.Collect();

Comment: Can anybody help me in writing compiled query for above code?